# Changing a page's URL parameters

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I want to add the parameter `&vhs=1` at the end of each YouTube video URL on my browser. I have tried using the following script but it gets stuck in a loop (keeps adding `&vhs=1` `&vhs=1...`).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Youtube Tape Mode
// @namespace   _pc
// @match       *://*.youtube.com/watch?*
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

var oldUrlPath  = window.location.pathname;

/*--- Test that "&vhs=1" is at end of URL, excepting any "hashes"
or searches.
*/
if ( ! /\&vhs=1$/.test (oldUrlPath) ) {

    var newURL  = window.location.protocol + "//"
                + window.location.hostname
                + oldUrlPath 
                + window.location.search.replace + "&vhs=1"
                + window.location.hash
            ;
    /*-- replace() puts the good page in the history instead of the
        bad page.
    */
    window.location.replace (newURL);
}
```

Can anyone offer some insights and advice as to how I can write the script for this purpose? I can't seem to figure out how to get out of the infinite loop problem.

Answer (score 2):

That script is *checking* the `pathname` but *setting* the `search` part of the URL.  In addition, it has at least one syntax problem.  Also, use `host` rather than `hostname`; it's more robust and portable.

So your script would be like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Youtube Tape Mode
// @match       *://*.youtube.com/watch?*
// @run-at      document-start
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var oldUrlSearch  = window.location.search;

/*--- Test that "&vhs=1" is at end of URL, excepting any "hashes"
or searches.
*/
if ( ! /\&vhs=1$/.test (oldUrlSearch) ) {

    var newURL  = window.location.protocol + "//"
                + window.location.host
                + window.location.pathname
                + oldUrlSearch + "&vhs=1"
                + window.location.hash
                ;
    /*-- replace() puts the good page in the history instead of the
        bad page.
    */
    window.location.replace (newURL);
}
```

---

Note that YouTube URL's always have something in the `search` part of the URL, so this code is fine.  For other sites, you may need an additional check and to add either `&vhs=1` or `?vhs=1` depending on whether the search was initially blank.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks for the original script btw!

Comment: You're welcome!  If this answer works for you, please [tick the check-mark next to it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).